# Sending data SAP Fiori launchpad webapp/SAPUI5 webapp from client side javascript

Tags: javascript, sapui5

This is a general question I have as I am exploring the world of automating some tasks in my workplace.

We have a portal/launchpad environment on our businesses website which has apps  shown as tiles.

One of these apps when opened has a homepage that has a bunch of search fields and selectors to interface with (I assume) SAP data.

Ultimately my goal is to be able to send a number to a specific search field on a client-side local webapp (just plain old HTML/jquery stuff) and execute a search for that number in the sapui webapp.

I am getting to an competent level with javascript/HTML/CSS but am completely lost as to where to start with this type of issue as the MVC stuff is completely alien to me.

All my experience has been in creating completely client-side web apps with mostly interface with a local MS Access database.

Is what I am suggesting even possible?

So far I can open the homepage by executing the following code that someone else in the organization used:

```
window.open('https://fiori.mycompany.com/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/z_cs_ch/index.html
```

Is it possible to add some form of string after a `?....` at the end of the url?

Again I am completely new to this and looking at the development guides in sapui website isn't shedding any light on it either. Possibly because I don't really know exactly what I am looking for!

Any help /guidance is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
After comments below I can see the request sent to server is in the following format:

```
Request GET /sap/opu/odata/sap/someotherlocation/SearchTerm('<variable to search for>')?$format=json HTTP/1.1
```

Am I right in thinking I could potentially send an ajax request to do something similar? If so, how do I go about it?

Thanks again

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that you want to automatically fill fields on a webpage?

Comment: I think so yes on a high level. However as this is a SAPUI app I have been unable to piece together a method to do so, I am assuming there is more to it than a regular webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promised here is what I got to work - actually got the overall method from an answer on here somewhere else.

This will send back enough detail that I can at least show the user some updates however after searching around I believe what I really need to be able to do is batch requests... I'm looking into Apache Olingo to see if that's possible.

```
    function orderSmmary(SO) {
    var uri = "https://fiori.<company>.com/sap/opu/odata/sap/<environment>/Details('"+ SO + "')?$format=json";

    var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http_request.onreadystatechange  = function() {
        if (http_request.readyState == 4  ) {
            var data = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
            // Do lots of awesome stuff with response
        }
    }

    http_request.open('GET',uri, true);
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Negotiate");
    http_request.send();    
}
```

Again this is an entirely clientside solution from completely outside any flori environment so I am hoping to stay completely javascript based.

Answer (score 1):

There are possibilties to achieve that but i think it's not a real good solution, to fill fields in another web application and to trigger the search.

It would be better if you know the backend service which is used by this Fiori App, and to integrate directly the service. If it's an Fiori App i might be an OData /REST Service. Odata/REST Service also can be called by HTML/jquery JavaScript stuff too.

In order to determine the Service URL and the payload which is used by the web app with the search field, just use Chrome Debugger Tools (or other Browser Debug Tools) and check under Network which server address and which payload parameters are sent to the server, when you trigger the search manually. Hope that helps you little bit.

Comment: Hi, yes it should be possible to create an AJAX GET request. Just use the XMLHttpRequest object in Javascript. Here you'll find a tutorial. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 1):

In the whole Fiori concept, it is definitely possible to have applications to call other applications and to get them to open up exactly at the point the user expects it. E.g. from a order click on a product to be brought to the material master, and have the material master app exactly show the product the user clicked on.

As you mentioned, this would indeed require the target application (that is navigated to) to support some parameters. You mentioned in your question already that you wondered if it would be possible to add a "?...." section to the URL. Fiori apps definitely support this concept, but how it is implemented depends very much on the app itself. In my previous example it could be as easy as e.g. adding `?product_id=abcde` though.

Fiori also has very nice extensibility concepts built-in. So if your target app doesn't exactly support the parameters you intend to pass, you could easily extend the app to support it, without having to rewrite of copy the entire app (which would be a disaster when you receive updated from the original developer).

To navigate from one Fiori app to the other, it is advised to use the `toExternal` method of the `CrossApplicationNavigation` service, which comes with the Fiori launchpad. This service allows you to specify parameters such as the app you'd like to navigate to, the intent (display, create etc), parameters (such as product ID) and a app specific route (e.g. /supplierdetails to see the supplier details of a product).

The CrossApplicationNavigation service is officially documented in the [SAPUI5 SDK](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ushell.services.CrossApplicationNavigation.html), but I'm afraid that the SDK doesn't contain a very elaborate description. However, if you Google for it, you'll find extensive information and examples on SCN and Stackoverflow on this topic as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the background and info on the possibilities. I have a barebones approach working now where I send an xmlhttp request and parse the response into JSON. So now my html/JavaScript app on clientside (homemade dashboard completely separate from flori) can show "product info" when the "product ID" is sent as per the edit in my original post. Don't have my laptop now but will post solution over weekend. However now I would like to extend the capability to achieve my goal of clicking the "product ID" and being brought to the "product" details  screen of the flori app. Possible?

Comment: Absolutely possible. The target app needs to support this though. It's quite fortunate that Fiori apps come with source code and can be enhanced though.